# Incluir nova tabela em diversos banco de dados Mysql de uma só vez

Tags: mysql, sql

Não sei se seria possível, mas pegamos um sistema feito em PHP/Mysql do qual cada cliente tem sua própria base de dados. Porém estamos criando mais uma ferramenta para esse sistema e claro, terá uma nova tabela nos bancos de dados. O problema é que esse sistema, como foi dito antes, tem ao total 23 bancos de dados e cada banco pertence a um cliente cadastrado nesse sistema.

É possível que, ao desenvolver uma nova tabela, incluí-la em todos esses bancos de dados de uma só vez através de algum comando SQL ou teremos que ir de um em um banco de dados para instalar essa nova tabela?

Comment: você considera a possibilidade de fazer isso via _script_? se sim, acredito ser possível (com _loop_)

Comment: não entendi bem o *"incluí-la em todos esses bancos de dados de uma só vez"*, se o banco está em cada cliente, terá que executar um script ou instalador em cada um dos clientes não é?

Comment: considerando que os bancos estão no mesmo servidor, minha ideia é carregar os nomes dos bancos e iterá-los criando a tabela nova. (não vou poder dar um exemplo agora, caso o comentário não ajude e/ou não consiga resolver, mais tarde eu tento..)

Comment: Olá pessoal. Isso. Está no mesmo servidor. Ele  tem uma revenda, onde tem esses clientes cadastrados. Ele pegou um revenda apenas para incluir esses clientes. Posso considerar via script. No início até pensei em fazer via script, mas pensei também que diretamente no SQL teria algum meio. Mas se for via script, é possível trazer o nome dessas bases de dados ou teria que colocar manualmente?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, você pode usar o código abaixo quando quiser alterar de banco, antes de executar o script de criação de tabela. Você pode fazer uma sequência ou um for.

```
USE DB_NomeBanco GO 
Select * from tabela
```

Comment: Olá Wellington, certo, mas existe algum meio de pegar o nome de todos os bancos de dados do servidor automaticamente sem eu ter que digitar um por um?